# Load all QML's from folder

Tags: qt, qml, swipeview

Is it possible to load all QML's from working directory subfolder to SwipeView? Amount of those QML's is unknown and will be changing in time (user may add new and delete old ones), so I think that I also need to reload (refresh) SwipeView when certain Button is clicked. All QML's are different, because they are being created depending on the information which user provides, in Python back-end (just the template is the same).

I've managed to make something like this:

```
SwipeView {
        id: job_swipe
        width: jobwindow.width/2
        height: jobwindow.height/2
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        Component.onCompleted:
            function load_jobs() {
                jobsignals.jobs_to_qmls_slot()
                var i
                var fn
                var fc = (jobsignals.filecount)
                for (i = 0; i<fc; i++) {
                    fn = "jobs/job" + i + ".qml";
                    job_swipe.addPage(job_swipe.createPage(fn))
                }
                //job_swipe.currentIndex = (fc-1)
            }


        function addPage(page) {
            addItem(page)
            page.visible = true
        }

        function createPage(jobfile){
            var component = Qt.createComponent(jobfile);
            var page = component.createObject(job_swipe);
            return page
        }

        function removePage(page) {
            removeItem(page)
            page.visible = false
        }
    }
```

But removing pages does not working as I want - it removes visually pages, but objects are still there, so when I want to add new page it firstly creates those which I've removed

Comment: Your question is too broad, so I recommend making it more precise, otherwise it probably cannot be answered.

Comment: Ok, so my first problem - how do you recommend to load QML's from folder to SwipeView? I cannot define static items in SwipeView and then only load them via Loader, because I don't know how much of them there is. Sample of what I've written is down here

Comment: @eyllanesc can you help me with completely removing pages in my code above?

Comment: Why do you mark an answer that, as you indicate in the comments, does not fulfill everything you ask for? I don't see the logic. Please read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely newbie when comes to asking own questions on stackoverflow. Forgive me. Next time I will try to divide one big question to several small and stick to links that you've provided to me :D

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with dividing your problem but your actions (previous comment and your acceptance of the answer) must be consistent. A simple and logical idea is: If an answer has not satisfied your requirements then you should not accept it. If you publish a new post where you ask for what you are missing then don't complain that we will close it as a duplicate.

Comment: The main title is "Load all QML's from folder" and JarMan gave me new solution in this matter and this is why I've accepted his answer. Beside that I'm asking you about help with my code so maybe in the future I may use it somehow. Sorry again and please do not hold it against me

Comment: The title is only a part of the post, your post is the title and content. IMHO the most important thing is the content as it explains the requirements and limitations, they give us a clear vision of what is desired that many times the title, having little space, cannot synthesize. And as I see in your content you clearly indicate: *But removing pages does not working as I want - it removes visually pages, but objects are still there*.

Comment: [cont.]  On the other hand SO we only dedicate ourselves to answer and not to guide in projects since it is a lot for us. That is why I have pointed out those links so that you know what we do and our limitations

Comment: [cont.] When a user visits your post in a few months or years they will read your post: The OP wants the .qml of a specific directory to be dynamically loaded, and that when the previous .qml is reloaded they will not appear. Surely like the OP I accept the answer, this must comply with all of the above, and it will run into the reality that it only fulfilled half of what was requested.

Comment: [cont.] Understand: The answers should not only serve you but the entire community, that is why they must comply with what is required.

Comment: Ok, thank you and at the same time I'm sorry you had to explain it to me. Post edited, so accepted answer match with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [FolderListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html) to generate a list of .qml files in a folder. Then you can load those with Loaders.

```
SwipeView {
    Repeater {
        model: FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel

            folder: // Whatever folder you want to search

            nameFilters: ["*.qml"]
        }

        Loader {
            source: fileUrl
        }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

To refresh the data, I unfortunately don't see a built-in method in FolderListModel to do that. But you should be able to reset the folder value (in a kind of ugly way), like this:

```
Button {
    text: "Refresh"
    onClicked: {
        var currentFolder = folderModel.folder
        folderModel.folder = ""                // First clear the folder
        folderModel.folder = currentFolder;    // Then set the folder again
    }
}
```

Comment: It is loading all files from folder in more elegant way that my code above, but do you know maybe how I can refresh all SwipeView so it can reload all pages with new model?

Comment: Unfortunately it still does'not work as I want, but I will try to manage it through my backend. One more question. Do you know why currentIndex property of SwipeView does not work when Repeater is inside?

Comment: Found solution: I needed to place 
onCountChanged: swipeviewID.setCurrentIndex(folderModel.count-1)

Comment: *inside of model